# Implementing custom database layer/classes, where should they go in Cake's app folder?

Tags: php, database, cakephp

I'm wondering where my custom database layer/classes should go in Cake's app folder.

1. Should I create them as components and store them in the components folder?
2. Should I create them as classes and put them in a class folder? If so, how would those be instantiated in my controller?

This means that all my controllers will have the following line:

```
var $uses = array('');
```

Edit: Basically, I'll be writing my queries by hand and will be calling my classes inside the controller. I'm wondering about the optimal way to implement this. I do realize that this involves tossing out the Model approach in CakePHP.

Edit2: I've tried using custom queries in my model - ie. Model->query('sql here...'). However, even though you can specify parameters to the query, I think they are not prepared/escaped in a fashion that protects you from sql injection?

Comment: Any specific reason why the need of having your own db layer on top of cake's db layer?

Comment: At this point, I think it'll be faster for me if I write my own queries. The model thing is making me look like a noob (which I find very frustrating :), I don't want to spam forums for help (need lots of it) and I need to get going on this project of mine. There's also the fact that I keep seeing several queries run when looking at the debugging (when in theory there should only be one) type of thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you just want to write your own queries.  You can do this with Model::query( SQL_STRING ).  In your controller,

```
function someaction() {
 $result = $this->Mymodel->query( 'SELECT name FROM users WHERE id=5' );
}
```

Your $result array will look a little weird, so I recommend using the CakePHP Set functionality to morph them into what you need.  http://book.cakephp.org/view/640/Set

Comment: Having SQL statements in your controllers is a bad practice. If you use SQL statements, put them into model methods.

Comment: @dhofstet: totally agree. @Travis Leleu: I've tried this before, however, unless I'm mistaken, I'm not protected against sql injection using this method (even though you can specify parameters in your sql).

Comment: @dhofstet agreed, if you're following the fat models/skinny controllers philosophy.  I just shortened it this way to simplify.  @tekius i think it still escapes your query string, but am not 100%.  Why don't you test it out to see?

Answer (score 1):

Database layer is linked to Model not Controller (or Component). Cake offers a way to implement that through Datasources: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1075/DataSources